# c++ which columns have 1s for each row in 2 dim array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I have the following 2 dim array. I want to find which columns have `1`s for each row.

So, when I run the following code I would expect to see:

```
0:02 1:13 3:01
```

However I don't get that.

Is there any suggestions?

```
#define MAX_N 100

int myArray[4][4] = {
    { 1,0,0,1 },
    { 0,1,1,1 },
    { 1,0,1,0 },
    { 0,1,1,0 }
};

int main()
{
    int K[MAX_N] = { 0,1,3 };
    int B[MAX_N];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        K[i];
        cout << K[i] << ": ";

        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
            {               
                // count = count +1;                
                if (myArray[x][y])
                    count = count + 1;

                if (count == K[i])
                {
                    B[x] = x; 
                    cout << B[x] << " ";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

if I change my initial array and make it as:

```
    int myArray[4][4] = {
    { 1,1,0,1 },
    { 0,1,1,1 },
    { 1,0,1,0 },
    { 0,1,1,0 }
};
```

I will get the following:

```
0: 02 1:013 3: 01
```

Is there any way to get the intersection of those? In other words, to get only a 0, since only the 0 is common across the rows when the column equals to K[i].                                                                                      So, the result would be:

```
 0:0 1:0 3:0
```

or even just

```
0
```

Hope it makes sense

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to get which rows contains `1` when column equals to `K[i]`.

```
int main()
{
    int K[MAX_N] = { 0,1,3 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << K[i] << ": ";

        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            if (myArray[x][K[i]]) {
                cout << x;
            }
        }
        cout << " ";
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

For your second question, add a `break;` after `cout << x;`.

Comment: almost at 1000 rep ... will help you on.

Comment: @Walter I'm a little excited to solve an unclear question. And thank you! :-)

Comment: Yeah, it was not so clear what I asked. Yes indedd, what I wanted is to get  which rows contains 1 when column equals to K[i]. So, this post answers my question. Thanks!

When one runs this code then the folloing is appeared:

0: 02 1: 13 3: 01 , which is what I want.

Comment: @AlPap Please say, and see if I can help.

Comment: if I change my initial array and make it as:

Answer (score 0):

When you want to see elements in a matrix you only need 2 cycles and instead create a new array for print the rows, you may print the index in the for.

```
int main()
{
  int count;
  for(int row = 0; row<4; row++){
    count = 0;
    for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
      if(myArray[row][col] == 1)
        count++;
    }
    cout<<"row "<<row<<"has "<<count<<" 1s";
    }
    return 0;
}
```